# Launch an application with command prompt using python

Tags: python, windows

I want to open a command prompt using python then i need to run a command on this command prompt which will launch an application.

Tried following code on Windows Server 2008R2, this opens and the command prompt and type the comand and when press ENTER it is giving error message:

`'C:\Windows\System32\CompMgmtLauncher.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

My code:

```
Popen(["start", "/MAX","cmd.exe"], shell=True)
wait(3)
print("Starting Application")
type("c:\\Windows\\System32\\CompMgmtLauncher.exe")
type(Key.ENTER)
```

Kindly help on this issue.

Comment: When run 'C:\Windows\System32\CompMgmtLauncher.exe' manually from commond prompt, it successfully runs the command

Comment: You might want to elaborate on which library this `type` comes from and why you're using that instead of directly using `subprocess.check_call` or similar...